# nested repeating groups CSV to XML in Java

Tags: java, csv, xml-serialization

I need to transform a complicated nested grouped csv file to xml. I will include a sample.
Because I do not yet know Java enough I am hoping to get some advise here.

```
MEPMD01,20080501,SUSNES,TEST:130000,45869713,1111111111,201010090016,,OK,E,SKWHREG,1.0,00000100,2,201010041359,R0,86,201010080359,R0,134
MEPMD01,20080501,SUSNES,TEST:130000,45869713,1111111111,201010090016,,OK,E,SKWH,1.0,00000100,48,201010041459,R0,4,201010041559,R0,4,201010041659,R0,1,201010041759,R0,0,201010041859,R0,0,201010041959,R0,0,201010042059,R0,0,201010042200,R0,2,201010042300,R0,0,201010050000,R0,0,201010050100,R0,0,201010050200,R0,0,201010050300,R0,0,201010050400,R0,0,201010050459,R0,0,201010050559,R0,0,201010050659,R0,0,201010050759,R0,0,201010050859,R0,0,201010050959,R0,0,201010051059,R0,0,201010051159,R0,0,201010051259,R0,3,201010051359,R0,3,201010051459,R0,3,201010051559,R0,0,201010051700,R0,0,201010051800,R0,0,201010051900,R0,0,201010052000,R0,0,201010052059,R0,0,201010052159,R0,0,201010052259,R0,0,201010052359,R0,0,201010060059,R0,0,201010060159,R0,0,201010060259,R0,0,201010060359,R0,0,201010060459,R0,0,201010060559,R0,0,201010060659,R0,0,201010060759,R0,1,201010060859,R0,0,201010060959,R0,0,201010061059,R0,0,201010061159,R0,0,201010061259,R0,2,201010061359,R0,4
MEPMD01,20080501,SUSNES,TEST:130000,45869713,1111111111,201010090016,,OK,E,SKWH,1.0,00000100,38,201010061459,R0,4,201010061600,R0,2,201010061700,R0,0,201010061800,R0,0,201010061900,R0,1,201010062000,R0,0,201010062100,R0,0,201010062200,R0,0,201010062300,R0,0,201010070000,R0,0,201010070100,R0,0,201010070200,R0,0,201010070300,R0,0,201010070400,R0,0,201010070500,R0,0,201010070600,R0,0,201010070700,R0,0,201010070800,R0,0,201010070900,R0,0,201010071000,R0,0,201010071100,R0,0,201010071159,R0,0,201010071259,R0,3,201010071359,R0,4,201010071459,R0,4,201010071600,R0,0,201010071700,R0,1,201010071800,R0,0,201010071900,R0,0,201010072000,R0,1,201010072100,R0,1,201010072200,R0,0,201010072300,R0,0,201010080000,R0,0,201010080059,R0,0,201010080159,R0,0,201010080259,R0,0,201010080359,R0,0
MEPMD01,20080501,SUSNES,TEST:130000,45877480,3232232111,201010090016,,OK,E,SKWHREG,1.0,00000100,2,201010041400,R0,5,201010080400,R0,7
MEPMD01,20080501,SUSNES,TEST:130000,45877480,3232232111,201010090016,,OK,E,SKWH,1.0,00000100,48,201010041459,R0,0,201010041559,R0,0,201010041659,R0,0,201010041759,R0,0,201010041859,R0,0,201010041959,R0,0,201010042059,R0,0,201010042159,R0,0,201010042300,R0,0,201010050000,R0,0,201010050100,R0,0,201010050200,R0,0,201010050259,R0,0,201010050359,R0,0,201010050459,R0,0,201010050559,R0,1,201010050659,R0,0,201010050759,R0,0,201010050859,R0,0,201010050959,R0,0,201010051100,R0,0,201010051200,R0,0,201010051300,R0,0,201010051359,R0,0,201010051459,R0,0,201010051559,R0,0,201010051659,R0,0,201010051759,R0,0,201010051859,R0,0,201010051959,R0,0,201010052059,R0,0,201010052159,R0,0,201010052259,R0,0,201010052359,R0,0,201010060059,R0,0,201010060159,R0,0,201010060259,R0,0,201010060359,R0,0,201010060459,R0,0,201010060559,R0,0,201010060659,R0,0,201010060800,R0,0,201010060900,R0,0,201010061000,R0,0,201010061100,R0,0,201010061159,R0,0,201010061259,R0,0,201010061359,R0,0
MEPMD01,20080501,SUSNES,TEST:130000,45877480,3232232111,201010090016,,OK,E,SKWH,1.0,00000100,38,201010061459,R0,0,201010061559,R0,0,201010061659,R0,0,201010061759,R0,0,201010061859,R0,0,201010061959,R0,0,201010062059,R0,0,201010062159,R0,0,201010062259,R0,0,201010062359,R0,0,201010070059,R0,0,201010070159,R0,0,201010070259,R0,0,201010070359,R0,0,201010070459,R0,0,201010070559,R0,0,201010070659,R0,0,201010070759,R0,0,201010070859,R0,0,201010070959,R0,0,201010071059,R0,0,201010071159,R0,0,201010071300,R0,1,201010071400,R0,0,201010071500,R0,0,201010071559,R0,0,201010071659,R0,0,201010071759,R0,0,201010071859,R0,0,201010071959,R0,0,201010072059,R0,0,201010072159,R0,0,201010072259,R0,0,201010072359,R0,0,201010080100,R0,0,201010080200,R0,0,201010080300,R0,0,201010080400,R0,0
```

The first row is describing the following records, some columns can be omitted.

This would be one record in xml

```
201010061459,R0,4
```

Comment: The string `201010061459,R0,4` isn't XML.  Before anybody can help, you need to post a meaningful question showing input (which you have), expected output (valid XML) and unless it's obvious, how you want to transform the input to the output.  It's not at all clear how the input relates to the output here.